# Arrow keys navigation doesn't work on li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Google Suggested queries on my search form. What I want to accomplish is to let user interact with result lists with keyboard using javascript/jquery,

I want user to

- Navigate up/down with arrow keys through the suggested list (not working)
- Cancel the list with ESC (currently working)

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/y8r41qd7/1/

```js
if ($("#suggest-results").length) {

    var li = $('li');
    var liSelected;
    $(window).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which === 40) {
            console.log("Succeed on down arrow");
            if (liSelected) {
                liSelected.removeClass('selected');
                next = liSelected.next();
                if (next.length > 0) {
                    liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
                } else {
                    liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
                }
            } else {
                liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
            }
        } else if (e.which === 38) {
            if (liSelected) {
                liSelected.removeClass('selected');
                next = liSelected.prev();
                if (next.length > 0) {
                    liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
                } else {
                    liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
                }
            } else {
                liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
            }
        } else if (e.which === 27) {
            $("#syrInputForm").val('');
            $("#suggest-results").html('&nbsp;');
            return false;
        }
    });
    $(".header input[name=tag]").keyup(function() {

        var searched = $(this).val();
        var gghref = 'https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&ds=yt&client=youtube&hjson=t&cp=1&q=' + searched;
        var result;
        $.ajax({
            url: gghref,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
                for (var i = 1; i < data[1].length; i++) {
                    if (data[1][i][0].length && data[1][i]) {
                        result += '<li class="gsuggested"><a href="#">' + data[1][i][0] + '</a></li>';
                    }
                }
                $("#suggest-results").html("<ul>" + result.replace("undefined", "") + "</ul>");
                $('.gsuggested > a').click(function() {
                    var valoare = $(this).text();
                    $(".header input[name=tag]").val(valoare).focus();
                    $("#suggest-results").html('&nbsp;');
                    return false;
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

```css
#suggest-results .selected {
  background: #CCD5DB;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
    <div class="searchWidget">
        <form action="" method="get" id="searchform" autocomplete="off" novalidate="true">
            <div class="search-holder">
                <span class="search-button">
        <button type="submit">
           <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
     </span>
                <div class="form-control-wrap">
                    <input id="syrInputForm" type="text" class="form-control input-lg empty" name="tag" value="" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="suggest-results"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever assigned `liSelected`.

Comment: @jmargolisvt http://jsfiddle.net/Vtn5Y/ pretty much the same logic, but works on this one

Comment: @Kaddath Thanks Kaddath, I tried it but now the thing is, it selects the first li, then the it disappears right away. I can just see it is getting selected but then after a few miliseconds, it disappears back to normal state.

Comment: @Pelin see my solution i posted

Comment: @Deckerz Now I see why it disappears, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Pelin if you could mark it as answer that would be great :)

Comment: @Deckerz Is there a proper way when I press enter, it searches the selected one instead of typed one? For instance i wrote `te` in input, when i selected `test` in the list and click enter, it searches `te` right away. I would really appreciate a solution or hint for this.

Comment: @Pelin add an if statement to the keyup function to check if its the enter and one is selected.

Comment: I did this, but still instead of selected text, it searches what I typed on `form:action`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below. You had to assign `li` in the window function and add a check on the typing input box keyup function to make sure it wasn't an up/down/esc key being pressed.

```js
if ($("#suggest-results").length) {

    var li = $('li');
    var liSelected;
    $(window).keydown(function(e) {
        li = $('li');
        if (e.which === 40) {
            console.log("Succeed on down arrow");
            if (liSelected) {
                liSelected.removeClass('selected');
                next = liSelected.next();
                if (next.length > 0) {
                    liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
                } else {
                    liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
                }
            } else {
                liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
            }
        } else if (e.which === 38) {
            if (liSelected) {
                liSelected.removeClass('selected');
                next = liSelected.prev();
                if (next.length > 0) {
                    liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
                } else {
                    liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
                }
            } else {
                liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
            }
        } else if (e.which === 27) {
            $("#syrInputForm").val('');
            $("#suggest-results").html('&nbsp;');
            return false;
        }
    });
    $(".header input[name=tag]").keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.which !== 27 && e.which !== 38 && e.which !== 40) {
            var searched = $(this).val();
            var gghref = 'https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&ds=yt&client=youtube&hjson=t&cp=1&q=' + searched;
            var result;
            $.ajax({
                url: gghref,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(data) {
                    for (var i = 1; i < data[1].length; i++) {
                        if (data[1][i][0].length && data[1][i]) {
                            result += '<li class="gsuggested"><a href="#">' + data[1][i][0] + '</a></li>';
                        }
                    }
                    $("#suggest-results").html("<ul>" + result.replace("undefined", "") + "</ul>");
                    $('.gsuggested > a').click(function() {
                        var valoare = $(this).text();
                        $(".header input[name=tag]").val(valoare).focus();
                        $("#suggest-results").html('&nbsp;');
                        return false;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

```css
#suggest-results .selected {background: #CCD5DB;} 
#suggest-results li.selected {background: #CCD5DB;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="header">
<div class="searchWidget">
<form action="" method="get" id="searchform" autocomplete="off" novalidate="true">
   <div class="search-holder">
      <span class="search-button">
        <button type="submit">
           <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
     </span>
   <div class="form-control-wrap">
      <input id="syrInputForm" type="text" class="form-control input-lg empty" name="tag" value="" placeholder="Search">                
   </div>
</div>
</form>
<div id="suggest-results"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Deckerz, It works as intended, But there is a slight issue I couldn't fix; When you type `mus` for instance, you can select the items, then when you continue typing, `musi` for instance, select doesn't start from the beginning on `musi` list, but it continues from `mu`, when you click down button several times, then it comes to the `musi` results. What would I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove the class of liselected if they type more

Comment: Keep getting `Cannot read property 'removeClass' of undefined`. Sorry for bothering you btw, I am quite newbie who tries to achieve something :)   `li.removeClass('selected');` does only remove the selected state but the order is still problematic